# Renderscript compilation doesn't generate files in 'gen' dir

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, renderscript

I have a renderscript in my android project which compiles properly. The .bc file generated looks correct and there's also the corresponding .class file that gets generated (ScriptC_...class). However, I can't seem to find the 'gen' directory.

How do I go about fixing this? I'm on AndroidStudio 0.2.5, API 17, gradle 1.7 and the buildsystem 0.5.+. Here's the project structure:

```
<root>
    .idea
    build
    <projectname>
        classes
            ScriptC_blah.class
    lib
    src
        main
            gen
            java
                ...moredirs...
                <sourcecode>
    app.iml
    build.gradle
```

Answer (score 2):

The new build tools place generated files in `$project_dir/build/source/`.

Under `source`, there are separate directories for `aidl,r,buildConfig and rs`.

Each further divided into `debug` and `release`.

**Update:** From my tests for a RenderScript named `test.rs`, with

```
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.android)
```

the Java sources are being generated at:

```
ProjectDir/build/source/rs/debug/com/example/android/ScriptC_test.java
```

Comment: That looks correct. I see the R.java file in one of those dirs (r/debug/.../R.java). But I still don't see the files that should have been there for RenderScript.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha Just tested. Yes, Java files are generated under `rs` directory in `build/source`. Updated answer.

Comment: Wow. The issue was I wasn't placing my .rs files in the 'rs' directory as specified here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure - It's working now. Thanks!